# Разница между statement, expression и block(инструкция, выражение и блок)

Tags: java

Что такое ***statement***, ***expression*** ,  ***block***(инструкция, выражение и блок) и какая между ними разница ?

Answer (score 4):

Выражение это фрагмент кода, результатом которого является некая величина.
Инструкция фрагмент кода, изменяющий состояние окружения в котором выполняется программа.

Это определение взял из книги по javascript(http://eloquentjavascript.net/), думаю оно действует в контексте любого языка. Но всё же любопытно: насколько оно исчерпывающее.

Из определения следует:

- sum = 2 + 3; - инструкция содержащая выражение
- var sum; - просто    инструкция без выражения
- 2+3; - просто выражение, но выражения без    инструкций
  бессмысленны(кроме случаев отладки) т.к. с    результатом
  нужно что-то делать/где-то хранить его.

Блок - набор из нескольких инструкций.

Answer (score 0):

**Выражение**(***англ. Expression***) — инструкция, присваивающая правую часть выражения левой части (выражает левую через правую).
**Инструкция** ( ***англ. Statement*** ) - в программировании, команда языка программирования, которым задается определенный шаг процесса обработки информации на ЭВМ.

**1.** Любое выражение — это инструкция. 
**2.** Не каждая инструкция — выражение. 

Пример кода:

```
a = 1; выражение
int a = 10;  инструкция и выражение (сначала [var a] — инструкция которая не является выражением т.к. присваивания нет, а потом уже [a = 10] — выражение, которое можно также назвать инструкцией).
if (a < 2){} else{} и т.д. — инструкция, но не выражение, ибо ничего не выражается, но действия происходят.


Точно также и с w = x+y+z :
1. x+y+z // инструкция, но не выражение.
2. w = //если вы введете сюда код что вернула инструкция (x+y+z) — выражение и инструкция присваивания одновременно
```

***Блок(англ. Block)*** - это 0 или больше инструкций помещенных между фигурными скобками и может быть помещен в том месте кода, где это дозволяется. Например:

```
 class BlockDemo {
             public static void main(String[] args) {
                  boolean condition = true;
                  if (condition) { // начало блока 1
                       System.out.println("Condition is true.");
                  } // конец блока 1
                  else { // начало блока 1
                       System.out.println("Condition is false.");
                  } // конец блока 2
             }
        }
```

Ссылки на источники:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html
http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/25447-raznica-mezhdu-vyrazheniyami-i-instrukciyami.html

Comment: Про выражение  не верно. Про Statement, впрочем, тоже. Похоже, вы их путаете в примере кода.

Comment: @ Nofate, можете править если что-то не верно, ответ открыт. Я сам хотел разобраться в этой теме, написал ответ исходя из информации на форумах, поэтому информация может быть недостоверной.